# ¿Cuál es la recomendación para responder una solicitud en una API REST?

Tags: java, spring, rest

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación Spring Framework 5, estoy en la parte de los controladores con las operaciones CRUD. El profesor que nos está enseñando su recomendación para responder solicitudes POST, PUT y DELETE es:

```
@PostMapping("/elemento")
public Estatus insertarElemento(@RequestBody Elemento elemento) {
    // Código para almacenar el elemento
    return new Estatus("Se ha creado el elemento", true);
}
```

Siendo `Estatus` una clase compuesta por dos atributos:

```
private String mensaje;
private boolean exito;
```

Pero nos comentó que existen otras formas, como usando `ResponseEntity`. Por lo que quisiera saber, cuál es la mejor opción para responder solicitudes REST, con Response Entity, devolviendo una clase centinela, u otra manera.
Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Con `ResponseEntity<T>` se tienen más opciones de respuesta ya que no se limita a atributos predefinidos (como los de tu clase `Estatus`) sino que se pueden adicionar headers y HTTP Status los cuales son muy útiles para controlar el flujo de la solicitud. Por ejemplo tu método con `ResponseEntity<T>` se vería así:

```
@PostMapping("/elemento")
public ResponseEntity<String> insertarElemento(@RequestBody Elemento elemento) {
    // Código para almacenar el elemento
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Se ha creado el elemento", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Fíjate que la respuesta lleva el status `HttpStatus.OK` (código 200) lo cual indica que la petición se realizó correctamente; pero si por ejemplo, por alguna razón el usuario **no** tiene permisos para realizar la operación el código sería el siguiente:

```
@PostMapping("/elemento")
public ResponseEntity<String> insertarElemento(@RequestBody Elemento elemento) {
    // Código para almacenar el elemento
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Sin permisos", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```

Por esto es que `ResponseEntity<T>` resulta una excelente manera para responder este tipo de solicitudes Rest.